# Class label order in YoloV5 using Ultralytics code

Tags: python, pytorch, yolo, yolov5

I was trying to train a custom object detector using [Ultralytics open-source research](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5). I encountered this problem at the step where we have to generate a .yaml file [here](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/wiki/Train-Custom-Data#1-create-datasetyaml). What should be the ordering of those label names? It is not alphabetical as we do in Tensorflow. I don't want my model to mislabel during inference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is arbitrary. You can choose whatever you want. The relevant part is that, in the [next step](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/wiki/Train-Custom-Data#2-create-labels), you must provide a `.txt` per image, where:

> Each row is `class x_center y_center width height` format.

In this case, `class` will be an integer between 0 and N-1, where N is the number of classes that you defined in the `.yaml` file.

So, if in the `.yaml` file you have:

```yaml
nc: 3
classes: ['cat', 'dog', 'car']
```

and in `my_image.txt` you have:

```
0 0.156 0.321 0.254 0.198
2 0.574 0.687 0.115 0.301
```

Then, it means that, in this image, you have one `cat` and one `car`.